# How to dynamically hide/show widgets?

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout

I want to dynamically hide/show widget like so:

```
Default:
|-------|
|       |
| text  |
| editor|
|-------|


With webkit preview:
|-------|-------|
|       |       |
| text  | web   |
| editor| widget|
|-------|-------|


With okular preview:
|-------|-------|
|       |       |
| text  | okular|
| editor| widget|
|-------|-------|
```

Comment: Can you check the QWidget docs if it has any sort of `hide` method or something? Or QLayout docs to see if you can `remove` stuff from them?

Comment: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide

Comment: Is that usually how you do something like that?(I thought there might be an optionally empty widget or something). Also you might want to submit one of your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 46):

Just add all your widgets into the layout and use `QWidget::hide()`, `QWidget::show()` when needed.

For more complex situations you can use [The State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html).